# Rationalizing denominator with cube roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rationalize the denominator of $$\frac{6}{\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{64}}$$ and simplify.

I already have an answer. I just want to compare answers with others. Maybe someone has different solutions? Also, I really disagree with the answer found at the back of the questionnaire.

Comment: What is your answer?

Comment: I got $2-\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: I feel it is wrong. It is 2- cube root of 2.

Comment: So the questionnaire IS WRONG. It answered 2.

Comment: $2$ can't be the answer, because the denominator is irrational, so the answer must be irrational as well.

Comment: Thank you guys for reassuring.

Comment: For future reference, it is better to include your own result (probably with a sketch of how you derived it) and the "back of the book" answer you doubt.  This allows Readers to more easily respond to your doubt.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for noting me on that one. I will make sure that I accomplish that one next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sqrt[3]{64}=4\;,\;\;\sqrt[3]{16}=4^{2/3}\;\implies$$

$$\sqrt[3]4+\sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{64}=4^{1/3}+4^{2/3}+4=4^{1/3}\left(1+4^{1/3}+4^{2/3}\right)=$$

$$=4^{1/3}\frac{1-4}{1-4^{1/3}}=3\cdot4^{1/3}\frac1{4^{1/3}-1}\implies$$

$$\frac6{\sqrt[3]4+\sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{64}}=\frac{2(4^{1/3}-1)}{4^{1/3}}=2^{1/3}(4^{1/3}-1)=2-\sqrt[3]2$$

Answer (score 7):

Use  $x+x^2+x^3=x\cdot(x^3-1)/(x-1)$ with $x=\sqrt[3]{4}$.
Hence 
$$\frac{6}{\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{64}}=\frac{6(\sqrt[3]{4}-1)}{\sqrt[3]{4}(4-1)}=2-2^{1-2/3}=2-\sqrt[3]{2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Write $x=\sqrt[3]4$, then the expression is
$$\frac6{x+x^2+x^3}=\frac1x×\frac6{1+x+x^2}$$
Multiply by $x-1$:
$$=\frac1x×\frac{6(x-1)}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$$
$$=\frac1x×\frac{6(x-1)}{x^3-1}$$
$$=\frac{x-1}x×\frac{6}{3}$$
$$=2\left(1-\frac1x\right)$$
$$=2\left(1-\frac{x^2}{x^3}\right)$$
$$=2\left(1-\frac{\sqrt[3]{16}}4\right)$$
$$=2\left(1-\frac{2\sqrt[3]{2}}4\right)$$
$$=2-\sqrt[3]2$$

Comment: :How did you made the transition from step 5 to step 6 i.e., how you wrote 1=$x^2$?

Comment: Isn't it just multiplying the numerator and denominator by $x^2$?

Comment: :OH! i just  overlooked it.